# Tish'a Ve'esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty nine?

### ?תשעה ועשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 329? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 329, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

When Mr T heard about lazy gematria, he said, "I pity the fool who uses it in an answer."

Comment: We have a user with that gematria in fact.

Comment: I'm glad to see the series up and running again.

Comment: @DoubleAA . . . .Don't we have users with *many* gematriyos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

סניגור = 329

328 = קטיגור

[Lachmei Toda](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7451&st=&pgnum=13&hilite=) explains that in order to switch from קטיגור to סניגור we need true Achdus.

Answer (score 6):

In the 329th year of the third millennium [AM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Mundi)<sup>1</sup>, 91 years after Ya'akov and family moved to Egypt, Tzefo the grandson of Esav<sup>2</sup>, known at the time as Janus Saturnus, king of the [Kittim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kittim#Account_in_Yosippon) in Italy, successfully beat back an attack by Africans who had been harassing the Kittim for years. A critical element of his success was his prayer to the God of his ancestors, Avraham and Yitzchak.

Emboldened by this victory, he decided to attack the Israelites in Egypt to "avenge the blood of Esav." The Egyptians initially rose to defend their land by themselves and were defeated by Tzefo, so the Israelites took over and, with God's help, beat him. Mistrust of the Israelites among the Egyptians in the aftermath of this action contributed to the Egyptians' later enslaving the Israelites.<sup>3</sup>

<sup>1. [Seder Hadorot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seder_HaDoroth), Third Millenium, [Year 329](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=96&hilite=)</sup>
<sup>2. [Bereishit 36:11](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.36.11)</sup>
<sup>3. [Me'am Lo'ez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me%27am_Lo%27ez) on [Parashat Shemot](http://www.headcoverings-by-devorah.com/ShemotMeamLoez.html)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

329 is the total number of פרשיות סגורות in the Torah: 48 in Bereshit, 95 in Shmot, 46 in Vayikra, 66 in Bamidbar, and 124 in Dvarim.

Source: Yehoshua Liebermann, "Biblical Statistics", page 241